# Sequelize association with one foreign key

Tags: javascript, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have a database that was originally created with Django that was setup for a single foreign key association, [here is the JSON dump.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/master/examples/cookbook-plain/cookbook/ingredients/fixtures/ingredients.json)

Now this would be mapped as:

```
export const Category = sequelize.define(
  'category',
  {
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'ingredients_category',
  }
);

export const Ingredient = sequelize.define(
  'ingredient',
  {
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true },
    notes: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, defaultValue: '' },
    category_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: Category,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'ingredients_ingredient',
  }
);

Category.belongsToMany(Ingredient, {
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
  constraints: false,
  through: 'ingredient_category',
});
Ingredient.hasOne(Category, {
  // foreignKey: 'ingredientId',
  constraints: false,
});
```

Now sequelize complains that it is missing a foreign key on the Category model, but while there is only a single category on an ingredient the categories are not restricted to that one ingredient. Can someone help me to make sense of this association?

UPDATE: For the final answer it was just an incorrect association setup:

```
export const Category = sequelize.define(
  'category',
  {
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'ingredients_category',
  }
);

export const Ingredient = sequelize.define(
  'ingredient',
  {
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true },
    notes: { type: Sequelize.TEXT, defaultValue: '' },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    tableName: 'ingredients_ingredient',
  }
);

Category.hasMany(Ingredient, {
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
});
Ingredient.belongsTo(Category, {
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongsToMany` is used on a relationship N:M so `ingredient_category` should be a third table. Now as I understand you need a relationship where `ingredients` 1:N `categories`, so a `Category` can have many ingredients, so you should use `hasMany`.

On your case you can't use `hasOne` because it creates the foreign key of ingredients on `Categories`, and `hasMany` will create the FK on ingredients.

```
Category.hasMany(Ingredient, {
  foreignKey: 'category_id',
  constraints: false,
});
Ingredient.belongsTo(Category, {
  // foreignKey: 'ingredientId',
  constraints: false,
});
```

[Here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#difference-between-hasone-and-belongsto) is the documentation: